# Can I "instantiate" (parametrize) prepared ui form by placing it in another form in Qt designer?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I created a simple form object representing some arbitrary name and value pair:

[image: image description]

It's intentionally very simple - any design is to be applied through the CSS styles. Apart from the UI, the form consists of C++ class that handles the data loading and custom property defined in Designer too - the name of the data source (eg. hostname).

[image: image description]

So I have two values I need to parametrize:

- the `Name` - the QLabel text
- the `datapoint` - some hostname. This will be later loaded by the C++ class and tell it what data should be loaded

I was Imagine I would be able to create "*instances*" of my form manually in designer and assign parameters to them. Like in this fictional image:

[image: image description]

Don't forget `datapoint` is the custom dynamic attribute. I am sure the described design can be easily carried out programatically, but I feel like the designer solution will be prettier - provided there's a legit way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's wrong, but the only way I can think of is making your Qt Designer aware of your widget. [Something like this.](http://www.ics.com/blog/integrating-custom-widget-qt-designer)

AFAIK, widget propagation doesn't allow you to edit custom properties without code, so you need a full widget support. My colleagues intentionally do whatever posiible from sources, not IDE& Forms, so that the project becomes more portable, but you are to choose yourself.

Comment: I, on the other side, want to do this in Creator, so that it's easy to edit for other people. And I can't see how C++ Qt code is more portable than C++ Qt UI form. I planned to use Creator plugin but I wanted to avoid that to right now, because the project is in startup and many things are undecided yet.